# Identify organisation based on its email domain?

Tags: java, email, dns

Is it possible to get identification details about organization based on its email domain?

Like, lets say, I have some email id, `john193@some-random-organzation.edu`, then could I identify this organisation using some Java API & domain name `..@some-random-organzation.edu` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's what the WHOIS database is for.

You could, for example, execute `whois googlemail.com` as a system call from Java to get some information about google, and parse the output.

You could also use the common Apache toolkit whois client, `org.apache.commons.net.whois.WhoisClient;`.

Other the rather rudimentary information about who's responsible for the domain, DNS doesn't hold much info on who is behind something -- if it did, it would probably be tremendously helpful in mitigation drug trade, money laundering etc.

Comment: ... and the information in WHOIS is often completely bogus, especially if the domain owner has something to hide.